# xml, html or xhtml in <xsl:output>: Which is the better choice?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

For historic reasons we have a mixture of

```
<xsl:output method="xml">
```

and

```
<xsl:output method="html">
```

and

```
<xsl:output method="xhtml">
```

inside an include-hierarchy of XSL files. Now we want to refactor so all XSL files use the same output method.

In the end we want to produce XHTML-output so I suppose the latter would be the best choice.

But what are the differences between those three output-methods and which would you use for what kind of solution?

**Edit:** I'm using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer by reading the XSLT 2.0 specification ([XSLT 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#xhtml-output)).

> Given an empty instance of an XHTML
>   element whose content model is not
>   EMPTY (for example, an empty title or
>   paragraph) the serializer MUST NOT use
>   the minimized form. That is, it MUST
>   output `<p></p>` and not `<p />`.
>
> Given an XHTML element whose content
>   model is EMPTY, the serializer MUST
>   use the minimized tag syntax, for
>   example `<br />`, as the alternative
>   syntax `<br></br>` allowed by XML
>   gives uncertain results in many
>   existing user agents. The serializer
>   MUST include a space before the
>   trailing />, e.g. `<br />`, `<hr />`
>   and `<img src="karen.jpg"  alt="Karen"
>   />`.
>
> The serializer MUST NOT use the entity
>   reference `&apos;` which, although
>   legal in XML and therefore in XHTML,
>   is not defined in HTML and is not
>   recognized by all HTML user agents.
>
> The serializer SHOULD output namespace
>   declarations in a way that is
>   consistent with the requirements of
>   the XHTML DTD if this is possible. The
>   XHTML 1.0 DTDs require the declaration
>   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>   to appear on the html element, and
>   only on the html element. The
>   serializer MUST output namespace
>   declarations that are consistent with
>   the namespace nodes present in the
>   result tree, but it MUST avoid
>   outputting redundant namespace
>   declarations on elements where the DTD
>   would make them invalid.

That means the answer is using `<xsl:output method="xhtml">`.

Comment: That makes no sense : XHTML is not the one worried about self-closing being used on those without empty content model.... HTML parsers have some issues with it...

Answer (score 8):

HTML will serialize as HTML, so the output may not be well-formed XML.  If you are only sending to browsers and don't care about being able to parse as XML then that may work for you.

XML will serialize as XML, so the output will be well-formed, but you may run into some issues with browsers using the output.  Small things, like self closing `<script />` and `<div />` elements.  In order to avoid that issue you would have to play games, like adding comments inside of the element (e.g. `<script src="someJSFile.js"><!--don't close my script tag --></script>`)

If you have an XSLT 2.0 engine and want well formed HTML output without the headache of worrying about how some elements are serialized, then use XHTML.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no `method:xhtml` to the `xsl:output` directive in xslt 1.0.

[wc3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp) agree with this.

As XHTML is an XML dialect, that's what I would use.

If, however you are using [xslt 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/), might as well use `xhtml`, since that's what you are outputting.