# libxslt's applyStylesheet() produces broken XHTML

Tags: python, xhtml, libxml2, xhtml-1.0-strict, libxslt

I've got an XML data file that I'm applying an XSL stylesheet to, using libxslt in Python.  Things are almost perfect, but every instance of `<hr/>` in the XSL file is being turned into `<hr>` in the output from `unicode(applyStylesheet())`.  This is pretty much all I'm doing:

```
style = libxslt.parseStylesheetDoc(libxml2.parseFile('template.xsl'))
xmlDoc = libxml2.parseFile('data.xml')
data = unicode(self.style.applyStylesheet(xmlDoc, None))
xmlDoc.freeDoc()
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there an option that I'm missing to make the output valid XHTML?

(My current plan is to append `.replace('<hr>','<hr/>')` to the `data =` line to just make it work, but it seems like there should be a better way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can we see the `template.xsl` file? Does it contain the `<xsl:output/>` tag? Is the `method` attribute of this tag set to `html`?

If it is, then libxsl automatically strips all `/` from self closing tags.

Beware that, `xml` output method does not always output correct html, refer to [xml, html or xhtml in <xsl:output>: Which is the better choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906263/xml-html-or-xhtml-in-xsloutput-which-is-the-better-choice) for more information.

As explained in the answer of the linked question, the best choice would be `xhtml`, but it is only supported by xsl starting at version 2.

Comment: Yeah, it had `<xsl:output method="html"/>` and changing it to `<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>` fixed the problem.  Thanks.