# XSL empty tag closing missing

Tags: xml, html, internet-explorer, xslt

i'm transforming xml to xhtml with XSL transformation, the problem is the input tag does not print slash in the end although i wrote this

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

the output must be like this

```
<input type='text' name='t1'/>
```

instead it displays it like this

```
<input type='text' name='t1'>
```

well i know that this is new in HTML5 but what about IE 6,7,8.

i tried the next but non of them worked

```
        <input type="text">
            <xsl:attribute name="size">
                <xsl:value-of select="size"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="content">
                <xsl:value-of select="content"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!--<xsl:variable name="slash" select="/"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$slash"/>-->
            <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="somewhere.js">/</script>-->
            <!--<script type="..." src="...">/</script>-->
        </input>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not closed? Maybe post us a complete XSLT with input that we can try to reproduce it.

Comment: there was a mistake in the question but i fixed it , i'm sure it's not closed (there is no '/' before '>')

Answer (score 2):

I think this may solve the problem by using the xhtml output:

```
<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>
```

This is new with XSLT 2.0, which will produce an output that is a valid XML but respects the conventions for making the XML acceptable to legacy browsers.

This does not exist in XSLT 1.0. Some XSLT 1.0 processors may offer it, but I don't know which ones. Otherwise with XSLT 1.0 you should make an XML output instead.

[Here is a thread about the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1906263/583513).

Comment: you mean to write this ?
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml"/>
if so then it did not work(no slash added to the end), but thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

This will output self-closing tags:

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```